# Is there a way to create a procedure containing "insert" and "delete" with user output?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

I created two procedures for insert and delete respectively and would like to add them into just one procedure separated according to user's output. Any suggestions on how to do that?

```
create table departamento (
dnome varchar(100),
dnumero int primary key,
cpf_gerente bigint,
data_inicio_gerente date
);
```

Insert procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure inserir_departamento(in pr_dnome varchar(100), in pr_dnumero int, in pr_cpf_gerente bigint, in pr_data_inicio_gerente date)
begin
    insert into departamento values(pr_dnome, pr_dnumero, pr_cpf_gerente,pr_data_inicio_gerente);
end //
delimiter ;
#drop procedure inserir_departamento;
call inserir_departamento('Teste', 6, 99988777767,'1978-11-11');
```

Delete procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure deletar_departamento(in pr_dnumero int)
begin
    delete from departamento
    where dnumero = pr_dnumero;
end $$
delimiter ;
#drop procedure deletar_departamento;
call deletar_departamento(6);
```

I tried doing this to "mix" both procedures, but without success (I just receive a syntax error message):

```
delimiter $$
create procedure modificar_departamento(in insert enum("i"), in delete enum("d"), in pr_dnome varchar(100), in pr_dnumero int, in pr_cpf_gerente bigint, in pr_data_inicio_gerente date)
    begin
        if insert == "i" then
            insert into departamento values(pr_dnome, pr_dnumero, pr_cpf_gerente,pr_data_inicio_gerente);
        else if delete == "d" then
            delete from departamento where dnumero = pr_dnumero;
        end if;
    end $$
delimiter ;
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Simply cre3ate a procedure which calls 1st then 2nd your SPs.

Comment: please do show the full error message when you ask a question about an error.

Comment: @ysth Sorry I forgot to do that. Error: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert varchar(1), in pr_dnome varchar(100), in pr_dnumero int, in pr_cpf_gerent' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` not `==`.  `elseif` not `else if`.  Don't use reserved words as variable or parameter names, or if you do put them in backticks.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=d47617244e8f9086a1f3979b7ab294a9)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but one thing remains. How can I make the choice between one of the two operations when calling the procedure?

Comment: When I use `call modificar_departamento("i", "Teste", 6, 99988777767,'1978-11-11'); `, for example I receive the following error:
"[42000][1318] Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE empresa.modificar_departamento; expected 6, got 5". Because the system want me to add the parameter for delete.

Comment: right, the way you are declaring it you need to pass `("i", null, ...)` or `(null, "d", ...)`.  Not sure why you did that?  I would just a have a single mode parameter like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=caecd591f969350b73c979f94a375047

Comment: That's a good solution but I wanted to delete a row without having to use all the paramaters. Like:
`call modificar_departamento("d", 6);`. Since my procedure has this: `delete from departamento where dnumero = pr_dnumero;`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975